# Separating big number to digits c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to separate the number to  digits. As I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I  am  using the ready solution found at the internet:

```
  int convert_to_digits(long long number,int n) 
   { 
    //n is the length of the number
    vector<int> digits(n, 0);
    while (number)
    {
        digits.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }

    reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());


    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    cout<<digits[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;}
```

Which works perfectly for some numbers:

```
convert_to_digits(1234567890123456,16)
```

prints

```
    1234567890123456
```

But:

```
convert_to_digits(1234567890123456789012,22)
```

suddenly prints

```
    9223372036854775807000
```

Questions:

1. What I am doing wrong and how to solve it? (I already am using long long as a type for number)

   2. I see the magic of number 9223372036854775807 as it is 2^63 − 1, but why it appears here?

UPDATE: this is an attempt for the solution of the project Euler problem 8, where the limitation for the length of the number is 1000 digits. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler008

Comment: Yes, you're using `long long`, but even `long long` has a limit. If you want any length, get a bigint library (or write something small by yourself: an array, each element is one digit...)

Comment: A `long long int` is not guaranteed able to represent values exceeding 2^63-1.   If the `long long` type supported by your compiler cannot represent larger values, your function will not be able to convert larger values.

Comment: What do you think the range of your input type is? And why?

Comment: Hi,

This is a part of a problem for project Euler, which I am trying to do  via the  hacker rank website. 

The length of the number is ≤1000

Not sure I understand what do you mean by range of your input ...

Comment: Would it help if I read it as char and work with the string?

Comment: 1000 what? If 1000 digits, you are not going to have to follow @deviantfan 's suggestion. There is no built-in datatype that will hold 1000 digits. `long long` is only good for 19 digits

Comment: 1000 digits, yes.

Ok, so I guess converting to string and doing it for the string will help?

Comment: About Euler #8: It doesn't say that you have to use an integer type. You can read the input as string. ... BUT: There are much better ways to solve this than trying all consecutive digit products. Finding a better way is the fun part in Project Euler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, activate your compiler's warnings. On gcc and clang, `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` do the trick.

Secondly, if you call `convert_to_digits(1234567890123456789012,22)` on a platform where `1234567890123456789012` is too big for a long long, undefined behaviour occurs; since `1234567890123456789012` is a literal constant, your compiler will warn you about the error.

Finally, why don't you use all the `std::` classes to do your dirty job?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned long long ull = 1234567890123456;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << ull;
    const std::string digits = ss.str();

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0 ; i < digits.length() ; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << digits[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile & run with `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`
Output: `1234567890123456`

[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22d000eb2c90f5fb).

Comment: For more specific needs, please update your question.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely learn a lot from this answer about the ::std types.

The problem still remains though as my number can be up to 1000 digits long.

Comment: Then you should use a class handling big integer. Start by looking that up on google and come back on a new question if some points are still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The bigest number of long long type is 2^63-1, that is the magic number 9223372036854775807. if you special a number than it, overflow! when you call the convert_to_digits(), the first parameter is not the value that you input.

In fact, if you need so big a number, you should write a class to process it. just using char*, array or vector to store the big number. and implement the add, sub, mul, div, and pow()